# Difference between foo = bar and foo{ bar }

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I was under the impression that `foo = bar` and `foo{ bar }` both did the same thing and it was just a matter of preference, but in my code `foo = bar` gives an error but `foo{ bar }` does not:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<bar>> bars;

bar& myFunction() {

    bar* b = new bar();
    std::unique_ptr<bar> foo{ b }; //works fine
    std::unique_ptr<bar> foo = b; //error
    bars.emplace_back(std::move(foo));

    return *b;

}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Afshin Actually, that's not the reason, see digito_evo's answer.

Comment: Note that putting the same raw pointer under the control of two `std::unique_ptr`s will lead to undefined behavior, because both pointers will try to delete the referenced object when their scope is left. Never put an object under the control of a pointer more than once or better yet only use `std::make_unique`, so that you don't even get a chance to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one does not work because `unique_ptr` has an [explicit constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr):

```
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;
```

The below line:

```
std::unique_ptr<bar> foo = b;
```

tries to call the above-mentioned constructor of `std::unique_ptr`. And because of the `explicit` keyword, that call to the constructor is invalid.

So only these two will work:

```
std::unique_ptr<bar> foo { b };
std::unique_ptr<bar> foo ( b ); // or this
```

Comment: @Gary Fisher You might also want to do it like: `std::unique_ptr<bar> foo { std::make_unique<bar>( ) };` so you don't have to deal with `new` directly.

Comment: Is there a difference? Why would you not want to deal with new directly?

Comment: @Gary Fisher No there is no difference. But in modern C++, you almost always want to avoid using `new`/`delete`. By using `make_unique<T>` you are hiding the use of `new`. And `make_unique` will call `new` behind the scenes. It also makes the code easier to read and a bit more modern.

Comment: Small correction: `explicit` doesn't cause the initialization to fail if the constructor is selected by overload resolution. It causes the explicit constructor to not even be considered in overload resolution for copy-initialization. So if there was another viable constructor which is not explicit it would be chosen even if it would have been a worse choice had the explicit one been available.

Comment: `make_unique` can avoid memory leaks in some situations. `foo(std::unique_ptr<A>(new A()), std::unique_ptr<B>(new B()));` might leak the `A` if the `B` constructor throws between the `A` being constructed and the `unique_ptr` taking ownership of it, but `foo(std::make_unique<A>(), std::make_unique<B>())` guarantees that this doesn't happen.

Comment: @NathanPierson Since C++17 that isn't a good example anymore, because the stricter order-of-evaluation rules enforce that the situation cannot occur. (But I don't have a good alternative one that applies to all versions.)